# Bash: give piped empty string a default value

Tags: bash

The following is what I want to achieve:

1. get the token value from the environment file called `.env`
2. if the token is empty then `curl` a auth server
3. pass the token to environment and run `npm start`

The `.env` looks like below:

```
TOKEN=xyzabc
```

The below is my current script:
`TOKEN=$(grep 'TOKEN' .env | cut -d '=' -f2) npm start`

But I don't know how to inject the logic listed in step 2, it is something like `curl auth.server`, Can anyone help out?

Comment: Getting the value of `TOKEN` can be done by sourcing the file.

Comment: `source ./.env; if [[ -z $TOKEN ]]; then curl auth.server; else npm start; fi` might be what you wanted. Can be done inside a subshell so not to pollute the current env variables.

Comment: That is if the env variable `$TOKEN` is empty run `curl` or if it is not empty run `npm`

Answer (score 0):

To detect the number of characters in a string: `${#STRING}`. If the grep to give `TOKEN` a value returns nothing the strings length will be zero.

```sh
TOKEN=$(grep 'TOKEN' .env | cut -d '=' -f2)
[ ${#TOKEN} -eq 0 ] && TOKEN=$(curl server.auth)
npm start
```

## Explanation

1. get the token value from the environment file called .env
   `TOKEN=$(grep 'TOKEN' .env | cut -d '=' -f2)`
2. if the token is empty then curl a auth server
   `[ ${#TOKEN} -eq 0 ] && TOKEN=$(curl server.auth)`
3. pass the token to environment and run npm start
   `npm start`